# Git Tools show different history

Tags: git, git-bash, tortoisegit, tfs-2015

We are trying to understand why we get different results when looking at the history/log for a file depending on which tools we are using. 
The repo is in TFS Git. 
We can clone it with GitBash or Visual Studio 2015 and we get the same varied results.
Given a specific file 
Using GitBash:

```
git log <filename>
```

returns nothing.

*update - I found this was caused by not specifying the entire path to the file. I was only using the filename. I still do not know why the most recent update in TFS is not displayed*

Using the TFS Web interface history shows 9 changes including 1 revert. 
Using TortoiseGit Show log returns 4 Commits. It does NOT show the most recent commit. However if I select the option to "Show Whole Project" I can find that latest commit.

Can someone explain the difference in what these operations actually do and why the results would be different?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on a file and Show log, TortoiseGit shows you the log only for that file. So, that file has changes only in those 4 commits.

When checking the "Show Whole Project" of Log Message dialog, it shows you whole project's history. So, you can see all commits, including the commits which are not related to that file.

About TFS, sorry, no idea! Wish the information above helps you.

Comment: This does not appear to be accurate. We have a case of a file that was modified on 4/19. The changes were white space only but there were definitely changes. In the TFS log it shows the changes in the TortoiseGit log it does NOT. This is the kind of problem we are facing.

Comment: Interesting! Could you please provide a testing repository on GitHub/GitLab?

Comment: that would be difficult. I have a copy of the repo in the state where the problem exists. However it's production code and I'm not going to push that to GitHub.

Comment: So, can you create a new repo and try to reproduce it on that repo?

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what is happening.

```
git log --all <path>
```

shows the changes that need to be applied to get the files to it's current state.

For purposes of discovering who did what to a file when this is inadequate. However

```
git log --full-history <path>
```

will give you every single change including every merge.

TFS Git as seen from a TFS Website appears to show a version of the history that removes the merge commits but also seems to include a few more commits than regular Git does. It also seems to include reverts and the commit that is being reverted.

What would be helpful would be a --full-history option in TFS Git.